# Fixed left navigation after a certain point with sticky header

Tags: jquery, css

I want to prototype a page with a sticky header which has a 'fixed' left navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/rkr2/R7BH7/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav">
        <div id="bad"> </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id = "container">
    <div id = "left"> </div>
    <div id = "right"> </div>
</div>
```

JS for sticky header:

```
var nav = $('.nav-container');
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        if (!nav.hasClass('f-nav')) {
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
            nav.hide();
            nav.slideDown("slow");
            $('#bad').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        // nav.slideUp("slow");
        $('#bad').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

Now, I want the "left" div to stay right beneath the sticky header post-scrolling(and remain there). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the stickyfloat plugin.

http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html

Just set the offsetY setting to however tall the topnav is and it will stay below it.

Comment: can you tell me what I am doing wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/rkr2/R7BH7/1/ I made the css changes for the container and the parent and called the function for the nav but it is not working.