# Is it possible to have a fixed menu below a sticky header without a fixed height?

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a fixed menu below a sticky header without a fixed height?

What I am trying to achieve looks like this:

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

let open = false;

function toggleMenu() {
  open = !open;
  if (open) {
    button.innerText = 'Close';
    nav.classList.add('open');
    root.classList.add('hide-overflow');
  } else {
    button.innerText = 'Open';
    nav.classList.remove('open');
    root.classList.remove('hide-overflow');
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

```css
#root {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}

#root.hide-overflow {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
}

.banner {
  background: cyan;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

nav.open {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 21.5px;
  right: 0;
  height: calc(100vw - 21.5px);
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <header>
      <div class="top">
        Header
        <button type="button">Open</button>
      </div>
      <div class="banner">
        Banner
      </div>
      <nav>Menu
        <ul>
          <li>A</li>
          <li>B</li>
          <li>C</li>
          <li>D</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
          <li>Duis id sem non risus blandit convallis in ac ipsum.</li>
          <li>Mauris iaculis nisi at tellus aliquet vestibulum.</li>
        </ul>
        <p></p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Aenean varius nulla sit amet ex aliquam porttitor.</li>
          <li>Fusce ut sapien ut diam elementum elementum.</li>
          <li>Maecenas vehicula dui a consectetur tempor.</li>
        </ul>
        <p></p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Morbi nec ante efficitur, malesuada lectus nec, accumsan massa.</li>
          <li>Donec vitae arcu sed nunc tristique cursus id et turpis.</li>
          <li>Ut mattis ante dictum congue egestas.</li>
          <li>Ut a odio gravida, faucibus erat id, fermentum felis.</li>
          <li>Suspendisse vitae libero feugiat, iaculis augue et, vestibulum ex.</li>
        </ul>
        <p></p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Proin eleifend velit sit amet gravida tempor.</li>
        </ul>
        <p></p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Nam ut tortor ut leo posuere pharetra quis efficitur nisl.</li>
          <li>Suspendisse efficitur elit in lacus mollis, eu facilisis orci vulputate.</li>
          <li>Donec vulputate purus ut ligula euismod, eu venenatis tellus commodo.</li>
          <li>Praesent semper dui nec mattis lacinia.</li>
          <li>Duis dignissim justo quis rhoncus maximus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

This works by offsetting the position/height of the `nav` by the height of the `header .top` element.

There are two related answers here which suggest a similar approach:

- [Fixed left navigation after a certain point with sticky header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346807/fixed-left-navigation-after-a-certain-point-with-sticky-header)
- [How to keep a sticky div below a fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247316/how-to-keep-a-sticky-div-below-a-fixed-header)

Is there any way to do this if the height of the header is not fixed?